# how to read characters and integers from a file?

Tags: c++

So I have a data file that looks something like this:

> x + y + z
>
> 30 45 50
>
> 10 20 30

The only characters I needed was the operators, so '+' '+' I was able to use `file.get()` to successfully get those characters and put them in an array. Problem is I need to get the next line of numbers, and assign them to the values x , y z . I know I cant use  .get() , I would have to use `getline`. Will i have to eliminate the `file.get()` and use `getline` instead for first part also?

I looked at some of the questions posted on here but none of them were quite like mines. **Note I'm actually going to be using these values for another part of my program, just used `cout` to see if my values were being read correctly**
Here's my previous code:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a=0;
    int n;
    fstream datafile;
    char ch;
    pid_t pid;
    int a, b, c, result;
   

    string line;
    datafile.open("data1.txt");

    if(datafile)
    {
      for(int i=0; i <9; i++)
      {     
        datafile.get(ch);
      
        if (ch == '*'||ch == '/'||ch == '+'||ch == '-')
        {
           operations[a] = ch;
           cout<<operations[a];
           a++;
        }

      }
    }

    else
        cout<<"Error reading file"; 
}
```

So this is how I was getting the first line of the file in the beginning. It worked like I wanted it to, may have not been the nicest coding but it worked. Nevertheless I tried to get the rest of the file, this time using `getline`, but instead of getting the numbers I was getting a bunch of random gibberish/numbers. I know if I use `getline`, the first line cannot be in my loop. I know this is how I would get the numbers.

```
 while(getline(datafile, line))
 {
   istringstream  ss(line);
   ss >> x >> y >> z;
   cout<<x<<""<<y<<""<<z;
 }
```

Comment: Your last while loop has the correct logic, you can put `while(!datafile.eof())` instead of `getline`. Also to convert to int, use `stoi()`

Comment: @awesomeyi Well in the last loop itself, when I put it in my program, instead of starting from the new line, it seems to start from the beginning. and then outputs the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following make sense for the first line, or am I missing something:

```
string input;
std::getline(datafile, input)
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    if (input[i] == '+' || ...)
    {
        operations[a] = input[i];
        a++;
    }
```

If you don't want to use getline, you could simply read the entire file stream (note that the bool is a rather naive way to handle the problem, I'd recommend something more elegant in your actual code):

```
bool first = true;
string nums;
int lines = 0;
vector<vector<int>> numlines;
vector<int> topush;
while (!datafile.eof())
{
char ch = datafile.get()
if (ch == 12 && first) //I don't know if '\n' is valid, I'd assume it is but here's the sure bet
    first = false;
else if (first && (ch == '+' || ...))
{
    operator[a] = ch;
    a++;
}
else if (!first && (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
{
    if (!(datafile.peek() >= '0' && datafile.peek() <= '0'))
    {
         numlines[lines].push_back(atoi(nums.c_str());
         nums.clear();
         if (datafile.peek() == 12)
         {
             numlines.push_back(topush);
             lines++;
         }
    }
    else
        nums = nums + ch;
}
```

Honestly, I can't be sure the above will work exactly right, I'd recommend you just modify your code to use getline exclusively.  You'll need to add #include  to get atoi.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
while(!datafile.eof()){
    string s;
    getline(datafile, s);
    istringstream in(s);
    string tmp;
        while(in >> tmp){
            int i = stoi(tmp) 
            //Do something with i....
        }
}
```